# Generating bytecode using asm

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have a code like this:

```
tracker.setValue(false);
```

for which I need to generate the bytecode via ASM. So using the tool, I found the bytecode instructions for the above line is:

```
ALOAD 0
GETFIELD example/MethodAdapter.tracker : Lexample/Tracker;
ICONST_0
INVOKEVIRTUAL example/Tracker.setValue (Z)V
```

so when I convert this to into an ASM code, which looks like this:

```
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETFIELD, "example/MethodAdapter", "tracker", "Lexample/Tracker;");
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "example/Tracker", "setValue", "(Z)V", false);
```

(this code snippet is written into `visitMethodInsn`) however running the above ASM with `-javaagent` for a test class , I get an exception saying:

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    TestClass.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @20: getfield
  Reason:
    Type '[Ljava/lang/String;' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'example/MethodAdapter'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @20
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'TestClass' }
    stack: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 02bb 0003 59b7 0004 4c2b b600 052b
    0000010: b600 062a b400 2a03 b600 30b8 0007 b1  

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I found the issue is happening with this line:

```
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETFIELD, "example/MethodAdapter", "tracker", "Lexample/Tracker;");
```

looks like `ALOAD` of `0` is not pulling out the proper `this` or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the code into your `main` function, which is static, and hence has no `this` argument. The first argument is the string array.